# Variable length input for a simple neural network (Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano, sequential

Can a variable length, i.e. `input_dim=None`, be applied to a simple neural network? Specifically, the Keras Sequential model. I've been running into errors when trying to employ the same concept. I've already seen the documentation that seems to support this functionality:

https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

But when I do the following...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(num_feat, input_dim = None, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_feat, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(Dense(num_feat, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(Dense(num_feat, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(Dense(ouput.shape[1], kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'linear'))
```

...I get this error:

```
ValueError: ('Only Theano variables and integers are allowed in a size-tuple.', (None, 63), None)
```

Any help, ideas, or clarification would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. (And you can't with the functional API either)

The weight matrix has a fixed size and this size depends on the input dim.

The possible variable dimensions are:

- In convolution: the spatial dimensions, but not the channels/filters

  - 1D: `input_shape=(None,channels)`
  - 2D: `input_shape=(None,None,channels)`
  - 3D: `input_shape=(None,None,None,channels)`
- In recurrent layers: the timesteps dimension, but not the features dimension

  - `input_shape = (None, features)`
- In any layer, the "batch" dimension, but this is not usually set unless you use `batch_shape` or `batch_input_shape` instead of `input_dim`

  - For Dense: `batch_shape=(None,input_dim)` or `batch_input_shape=(None,input_dim)`

Comment: What if I add a recurrent layer or multiple recurrent layers for the sequential model?

Comment: The first question is "what do you want to do and why?" Then you choose what to use.

Comment: I am trying to make a single prediction for multiple sports statistical categories (63 in total). But the number of samples I have vary. My training data is a vector of 9 samples, but my test data is a vector of 7 samples. I thought using an input_shape of (None, 63) would accomplish this goal. My output is only a vector of 4 samples (4, 63)

Comment: What are you calling "samples"? If you have 9 input samples, you must have 9 output samples. If you have 7 input samples, then you must have 7 output samples. For that you need `inpup_dim=63`, or `input_shape=(63,)`.

Comment: Sorry for clarification: The input is a nested vector of 9 vectors with 63 features. It looks something like this [ [1, 2, 3, ..., 63], [1, 2, 3, ..., 63], .... ]. The output is the same format but only 4 vectors long.

Comment: It works for perfectly as I'd like for only a single player. But I'd like to extrapolate it be general enough to work for any player with a nested vector of n vectors with 63 features each. The output is always only 4 vectors long.

Comment: Can you please describe the shapes and the exact meanings of you data? What is 4? Where does it come from? What are you doing with the 9 input players?

Comment: Basically, I am interested in running predictions on a player’s next 4 games based on previous games. For each game (n) a player has 63 statistical categories recorded. In the current example, n=9. There are 9 previous games, each with 63 categories, for me to use as predictors for the output that is the player’s performance in the 63 categories across the next 4 upcoming games.

Comment: Aaaah, then you need `input_shape=(None,63)`. Meaning your data will be `(players, games, 63)` with any number of players or games. 

You must only pay attention to the arrays you create, it's not possible to create a numpy array with variable dimensions, so you should look for padding + masking layers or training each player at a time.

Comment: I already planned on training each player at a time. But the number of games is the only variable dimension. Does that still work? When you say input_shape, we are talking of RNNs still correct?

Comment: Any layer that supports that kind of input. Dense supports that, but it will see no relation between games.

Comment: A RNN, such as `LSTM` might be a good idea if the "sequence" of the games is important, if not it's just too much.