# InvalidArgumentError: Only one input size may be -1, not both 0 and 1

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

This is the error i'm getting when i'm trying to build a sequence-2-Sequence(encoder-decoder model) with attention(baidhanu) at model.fit i'm facing argument error can anyone correct me what is the exact issue

```
#Bahdanu attention 
#parameters to pass this attention 
'''
1.Encoder state's i.e.., state_c, state_h
2.encoder_outputs 
3.decoder_embedding which is in decoder part 
4.you will get a context vector named "input_to_decoder" pass this as input to decoder lstm layer 
'''
def Attention_layer(state_h,state_c,encoder_outputs,decoder_embedding):

  d0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_1')
  d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_2')
  d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_3')
  #hidden_with_time_axis_1 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(state_h, 1)
  #hidden_with_time_axis_1 = state_h
  #hidden_with_time_axis_2 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(state_c, 1)
  #hidden_with_time_axis_2 = state_c
  #hidden_states = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([state_h,state_c],axis=-1)
  #all_states = tf.keras.layers.concatenate()
  score = d0(tf.keras.activations.tanh(encoder_outputs) + d1(state_h) + d2(state_c))
  attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(score, axis=1)
  context_vector = attention_weights * encoder_outputs
  context_vector = tf.keras.backend.sum(context_vector, axis=1)
  context_vector = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(context_vector, 1)
  context_vector = tf.keras.backend.reshape(context_vector,[-1,-1,1024])
  input_to_decoder = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([context_vector,decoder_embedding], axis=-1)

  return input_to_decoder
```

Above is my attention layer

```
#Encoder inputs 
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,),name='encoder_input_layer')
encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 1024, mask_zero=True,name='encoder_embedding_layer')(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs , state_h , state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1024, return_state=True)(encoder_embedding)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c] 
# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,),name='decoder_input_layer')
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the. 
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 1024, mask_zero=True,name='decoder_embedding_layer')(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1024, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
#Attention layer which is defind in above function 
attention_layer = Attention_layer(state_h, state_c, encoder_outputs, decoder_embedding)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(attention_layer, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
output = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = tf.keras.models.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], output)
#compiling the model 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
#model summary
model.summary()
```

when i'm trying to fit the function i'm getting stuck with below error, i'm not understanding what it was

```
%%time 
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_output_data, batch_size=86, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2) 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Output :
Train on 4644 samples, validate on 1162 samples
Epoch 1/10
  86/4644 [..............................] - ETA: 8:18
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-781d7ca43c98> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', 'model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_output_data, batch_size=86, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2) ')

14 frames
</usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-60> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

<timed eval> in <module>()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError:  Only one input size may be -1, not both 0 and 1
     [[node model/tf_op_layer_Reshape/Reshape (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_16029]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

can anyone help me where i did mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely with these lines:

```
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,),name='encoder_input_layer')
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,),name='decoder_input_layer')
```

You cannot use `shape=(None,)` and must specify at least the number of features you have in your input.

To elaborate on the error you get, the batch dimension is automatically accounted for, it expects the 0 dimension to be -1 (or equivalently `None`) - you always have the option of varying your batch size. But dimension 1 cannot also be `None` (which is what you are currently setting) since there is only one non-batch feature dimension. Your model does not know what size your feature inputs are.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292010/variable-length-input-for-a-simple-neural-network-keras) gives a little more info on valid shapes for different kind of model inputs.

Comment: hi adamconkey, thanks for that after changes as per your suggestions i still getting below error

Comment: hi adamconkey, thanks for that after changes as per your suggestions i still getting below root errors [click here to see my error](https://codeshare.io/5Oqp77)